# See print in python script running on spark with spark-submit

Tags: bash, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

I have to test some code using Spark and I'm pretty new to it.

The code I have runs an `ETL script` on a cluster. The ETL script is written in `Python` and have several prints in it but I'm unable to see those prints. The Python script is added to the `spark-submit` in the `--py-files` tag. I don't if those prints are unreachable since they are happening in the `YARN` executors and I should change them to logs and use log4j or add them to an accumulator reachable by the driver.

Any suggestions would help.

The final goal is to see how the execution of the code is going.I don't know if simple prints is the best solution but it was already in the code I was given to test.

Comment: In general, spark has a web UI with the port 4040 and you can find the jobs and logs from there.

Comment: But that's only available while the job is running, right?

Comment: Then check the spark history server.

Comment: The prints should be visible in the history server?